# Where to get json data for map creation?

Tags: json, dictionary, d3.js

Where can I find json data for Tunisia to create a map with d3.js? 
If there are better tools to create a map (than d3.js) I'll be pleased to know about that.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mtimet/tnacmaps) is the first result I get when I google for "geojson tunisia".

Comment: I looking for some official source for the data. Is there a an official organisation that offers this kind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get what you need from [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com). If that's not sufficient, try the [Humanitarian Response COD/FOD registry](https://cod.humanitarianresponse.info/search/field_country_region/465) - this is UN data, and thus somewhat official. In both cases, you'll probably need to convert a shapefile to geojson - see http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/ for some conversion strategies.